# How can IPP improve OpenCV application? And how can I integrate it?

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, computer-vision, intel-ipp

I was wondering:

1. How can [Intel IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) make OpenCV applications faster?
2. How can I integrate it in already written in already written OpenCV applications?

I didn't find an immediate answer ([this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-open-source-computer-vision-library-opencv-faq) document doesn't really say much), but finally I found this question which answer has a clear example which answer to question 1. and partially to 2.

However, I have an observation:

1. Could the `(const Ipp8u*)&img.data[0]` casting considered inefficient?
2. I want to improve SURF descriptor exploting parallel computing and vectorization. Could IPP help me?
3. How can I develop my OpenCV in both cases that IPP is present on the target machine or not?

Comment: Check for example [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp)... in practice it's a bunch of `#ifdef` to check if IPP is enabled or not

Comment: @Miki ok that makes sense, thank you. Can you **please** look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010129/intel-parallel-studio-for-improving-opencv) question? I've no idea how I can modify OpenCV CMake to make it work with Intel parallel studio tools

Comment: Already seen that... no idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can share you an usage example of OpenCV and IPP functions in one console application. As you can see OpenCV Mat can be used in IPP functions which are usually faster then IPP functions.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Vfw.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgcodecs\imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"

#include <ipp.h>
#include <ipps.h>
#include <ippi.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    Mat img=imread("d:\\MyFolder\\sample_02.jpg");
    Mat grayImg=img.clone();
    cvtColor(img,grayImg,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat outImg = grayImg.clone();
    int step = img.cols;
    const Ipp32s kernel[9] = {-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1};
    IppiSize kernelSize = {3,3};
    IppiSize dstRoiSize = {img.cols - kernelSize.width + 1, img.rows - kernelSize.height + 1};
    IppiPoint anchor = {2,2};
    int divisor = 1;

    IppStatus status = ippiFilter_8u_C1R((const Ipp8u*)&grayImg.data[0], step,(Ipp8u*)&outImg.data[0], step, dstRoiSize,kernel, kernelSize, anchor,divisor);
    namedWindow("Source image",CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
    imshow("Source image", img);
    namedWindow("Output image",CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
    imshow("Output image", outImg);
    waitKey();
}
```